# Can I trust imageres.dll system icons indexes?

Tags: windows, winapi

I made a custom directory tree control which uses system icons extracted from `imageres.dll` file. I mean the file is read from Windows directory, so there will be multiple versions of the file depending on Windows versions.

Here's the exact C# fragment:

```
ImageList.Images.Add("Folder", ExtractSystemIconBitmap("imageres.dll", 4));
ImageList.Images.Add("File", ExtractSystemIconBitmap("imageres.dll", 2));
```

On my Windows 10 it looks OK, but will it work with different Windows versions like Vista, 7, 8 and 8.1?

My program will require at least Windows Vista to run (due to dependency on .NET Framework 4.5).

More precise question is - are those icon indexes constant from Windows Vista to Windows 10? If not - what would be a better approach?

Comment: You can get icons for files and folders from the system image list using `SHGetFileInfo`, much better than grovelling DLLs for the images yourself.

Comment: It looks like it's the best option, however I'm not sure about the size of the icon I would get. I don't understand why my question got downvoted. "This question doesn't show any research effort"? Well, I've done working code, I just asked if it's compatible.

Comment: Very unlikely that these indexes are guaranteed stable between versions. Why don't you just do it properly instead of hacking.

Comment: I don't know why your question got downvoted either, these things happen. If you see the docs for `SHGetFileInfo` you'll see it can return you the large or small icon as an `HICON`, or as an index. If you get it as an index you can use `SHGetImageList` to get any size of the system image list you want and then extract the icon manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to get the icons is to use [`SHGetStockIconInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762205(v=vs.85).aspx). It will tell you where the icon is in the current version of Windows.

If you want the system's current folder icons (which may not be the standard ones due to user customization), use `SHGetFileInfo`.

Comment: Just note that `SHGetStockIconInfo()` is only available on Vista and later.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Imageres.dll is only available on Vista and later, so that is not a meaningful restriction.

Comment: my point was that on XP and earlier (all the way back to 9x/NT4), one can still use `SHGetFileInfo()` to get default folder icons, even though `imageres.dll` is not available.  Use `SHGetStockIconInfo()` when available, fallback to `SHGetFileInfo()` when not available.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The function to use depends on what your goal is. If your goal is to get "the icon that Explorer is currently using for folders", then `SHGetFileInfo` is correct even on Vista and higher. If your goal is to get "the icon that Explorer uses for folders by default (ignoring any user customizations)", then `SHGetStockIconInfo` is what you want.